# Dynamically calculating square footage based on a formula

Tags: reactjs, eval, formik, yup

I am building an app using React/Formik/Yup, and a Node/Express API + Postgres database.  One function of the app requires calculating the square footage of a box/other cardboard packaging based on the style of the package and the associated formula.  An example would be an "RSC" style box with a formula of `((length * 2 + width * 2 + x1) * (height * 2)) / 144`.  Both of these are stored as strings in an object in my database.

My current solution functions, but if the user leaves out a required field, the app crashes. 
The part I'm having trouble with is the required fields change from design to design.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// importing axios for http requests
import axios from 'axios'; 

// Formik/yup (form validation library) import
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from 'formik'
import * as yup from 'yup'; 

// styling imports 
import './BoxCalculator.scss'; 

const BoxCalculator = ({ values,  touched, errors }) => {

    //useState hook to store options we dynamically render in the <select> tag
    const [ boxStyles, setBoxStyles ] = useState(); 

    // pulling the list of possible box formulas from the API on page render, going to save it to an array
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/box-styles')
        .then(res => {
            setBoxStyles(res.data.data); 
            console.log(boxStyles); 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err); 
        }); 
    // this next line eliminates the linter error causes by having an empty dependency array
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])

    const calculateFootage = () => {
        // selecting the Box Style the user has selected
        const style = document.getElementById('style').value; 

        // filtering the array to find the box_style_formula based on the 
        let styleFormulaArr = boxStyles.filter(box => box.box_style_name === style)
        let formula = styleFormulaArr[0].box_style_formula;

        formula = formula.replace(/length/gi, values.length)
        formula = formula.replace(/width/gi, values.width)
        formula = formula.replace(/height/gi, values.height) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x1/gi, values.x1) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x2/gi, values.x2) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x3/gi, values.x3)   
        formula = formula.replace(/x4/gi, values.x4) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x5/gi, values.x5) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x6/gi, values.x6) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x7/gi, values.x7) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x8/gi, values.x8) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x9/gi, values.x9) 
        formula = formula.replace(/x10/gi, values.x10)

        // disabling the "eval may be harmful" error READ TO UNDERSTAND WHY: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-eval
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        const decimal = eval(formula); 


        document.getElementById('sqft').value = `${decimal.toFixed(4)} sq. ft` 
        console.log(document.getElementById('sqft').value)

    }


    if(boxStyles) {
        return ( 
            <>
                <Form className="boxcalc-wrapper">
                    <label>Box Style:<br/>
                        {touched.style && errors.style && <p>{errors.style}</p>}
                        <select type="number"
                        name="style"
                        multiple={false}
                        id="style"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        >
                            {boxStyles.map((opt) => {
                                return (<option key={opt.id}>{opt.box_style_name}</option>)
                            })}
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>Length:<br/>
                        {touched.length && errors.length && <p>{errors.length}</p>}
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="length"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>Width:<br/>
                        {touched.width && errors.width && <p>{errors.width}</p>}
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="width"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>Height:<br/>
                        {touched.height && errors.height && <p>{errors.height}</p>}
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="height"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X1:<br/>
                        {touched.x1 && errors.x1 && <p>{errors.x1}</p>}
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x1"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X2:<br/>
                        {/* {touched.x2 && errors.x2 && <p>{errors.x2}</p>} */}
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x2"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X3:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x3"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X4:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x4"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X5:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x5"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X6:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x6"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X7:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x7"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X8:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x8"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X9:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x9"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>X10:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="x10"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label> */}
                    <label>Name Box:<br/>
                        <Field type="number"
                        name="name"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button className="calculate-box" onClick={calculateFootage}>Calculate</button>
                    <label>Square Footage:<br/>
                        <Field 
                        type="text"
                        name="footage"
                        className="boxcalc-field"
                        id="sqft"
                        readOnly={true}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <p className="save-question">Need to save this box?</p>
                    <div className="save-btn-wrapper">
                        <p className="no-thanks">No thanks</p>
                        <button className="save-btn">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </>
         );
    } else {
        return <p></p> 
    } 
}

const FormikBoxCalculator = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues({ style, length, width, height, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, name, sqft, boxStyles }) {
        return {
            style: style || '',
            length: length || '',
            width: width || '',
            height: height || '',
            x1: x1 || '',
            x2: x2 || '', 
            x3: x3 || '', 
            x4: x4 || '', 
            x5: x5 || '', 
            x6: x6 || '', 
            x7: x7 || '', 
            x8: x8 || '', 
            x9: x9 || '', 
            x10: x10 || '',  
            name: name || '',
            sqft: sqft || '',
            boxStyles: boxStyles || ''
        }
    }, 

     ============= YUP VALIDATION SCHEMA ===============
     validationSchema: function createSchema() {
         return yup.object().shape({
             style: yup.string().required("Style is required"),
             length: yup.number().required("Length is required"),
             width: yup.number().required("Width is required"),
             height: yup.number().required("Height is required"),
         })}, 

     ============== END SCHEMA ==============

})(BoxCalculator); 



export default FormikBoxCalculator;
```

Does anyone know of a clean way to only require the fields that the current design is using? 
ex. `((length * 2 + width * 2 + x1) * (height * 2)) / 144` would have the required fields of length, width, height, and x1.

I would also like some input on my use of "eval" in the calculateFootage function.  I've read at the docs for it (linked in the comments above my usage of it) and here on SO that there is almost always a better solution, but eval was the only thing I could get working.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over a set of attributes in the function and only do the replacement if it is in the function and is thus a require field for that function?

This might look like,

```
const attrs = ['length', 'width', 'height', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', .... etc]
for (i in attrs) {
  const attr = attrs[i];
  if (attr in formula) {
    formula = formula.replace(attr, values[attr])
  }
}
```